# How can you determine the hostname associated with an IP on the network?

Tags: networking, hostname, ip-address

How can you determine the hostname associated with an IP on the network? *(without configuring a reverse DNS)*

This was something that I thought was impossible.  However I've been using [Fing](https://www.fing.com/products/fing-app) on my mobile.  It is capable of finding every device on my network (presumably using an arp-scan) and listing them with a hostname.

For example, this app is capable of finding freshly installed Debian Linux devices plugged into a home router, with no apparent reverse DNS.

As far as I know neither [ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)), nor [Neighbor Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol), nor [arp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) include a hostname.  So how can fing be getting this for a freshly installed Linux PC?  What other protocol on a Linux machine would give out the machine's configured hostname?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [zeroconf](http://www.zeroconf.org/) protocol suite ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)) could provide this information.

The best known implementations are AllJoyn (Windows and others), Bonjour (Apple), Avahi (UNIX/Linux).

Example showing a list of everything on a LAN (in this case not very much):

```
avahi-browse --all --terminate
+  ens18 IPv6 Canon MG6650                                  _privet._tcp         local
+  ens18 IPv4 Canon MG6650                                  _privet._tcp         local
+  ens18 IPv6 Canon MG6650                                  Internet Printer     local
+  ens18 IPv4 Canon MG6650                                  Internet Printer     local
+  ens18 IPv6 Canon MG6650                                  UNIX Printer         local
+  ens18 IPv4 Canon MG6650                                  UNIX Printer         local
+  ens18 IPv6 Canon MG6650                                  _scanner._tcp        local
+  ens18 IPv4 Canon MG6650                                  _scanner._tcp        local
+  ens18 IPv6 Canon MG6650                                  _canon-bjnp1._tcp    local
+  ens18 IPv4 Canon MG6650                                  _canon-bjnp1._tcp    local
+  ens18 IPv6 Canon MG6650                                  Web Site             local
+  ens18 IPv4 Canon MG6650                                  Web Site             local
+  ens18 IPv6 SERVER                                        _device-info._tcp    local
+  ens18 IPv4 SERVER                                        _device-info._tcp    local
+  ens18 IPv6 SERVER                                        Microsoft Windows Network local
+  ens18 IPv4 SERVER                                        Microsoft Windows Network local
```

More specifically, you can use `avahi-resolve-address` to resolve an address to a name.

Example

```
avahi-resolve-address 192.168.1.254
192.168.1.254 router.roaima...
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you may use `dig` or  `host`. Example:

```
dig -x 192.0.2.1

host 192.0.2.1
```

In windows you may use `ping -a` like so:

```
ping -a 192.0.2.1
```

Comment: as far as I know `dig` and `host` are reverse DNS.  This requires special DNS setup to work.  That is it couldn't just find the hostname for a new device plugged onto the network.